genetic optimizer using pulp library
Is it possible to solve a linear problem using the pulp library to create decision variables and write fitness functions and penalties using the Pypi genetic algorithm library? I have done this, but it doesn't generate correct answers. Do they support each other?

No. This is impossible!
In general, you can assume that every modelling- and solver-tool in mathematical-optimization assumes, that it's in full control of everything after getting instantiated / triggered. External interference (without an API)  is always forbidden!
While there are methods of creating math-opt / metaheuristic=gen-prog hybrids, these are:

extremely complex
in need of careful communication in-between the components

e.g. plugin system in math-opt component: see for example SCIP Plugin API (probably the most configurable math-opt solver)


usually a multi-month work endevaour

It's not so easy to express why approach is impossible due to the complexity of mathematical-optimization, but just two simple remarks:

pulp (afaik) doesn't even let you inject primal-feasible solutions during search (let alone check non-guaranteed primal-feasible ones)

probably a req for something like that


pulps chosen backend solver will usually remove tons of variables and potentially heavily rewrite your problem

without accurate (e.g. plugin-API) communication, an external component would want to do something to variables not even existing anymore




Keep in mind, that things are even much more strict than that: Often people use Python-native if or max functions on math-opt entities (e.g. variables) during modelling (let's call it compile-time) expecting it do something during solve / search (let's call it runtime).
This is also wrong for the same reasons AND because these things (as unknown to pulp and co.) are eagery evaluated by python before the math-opt tool even sees it!
